# how to fix vulnerabilities npm manually angular

Tags: angular, npm

how can i fix vulnerabilities npm manually in angular. 
i try to solve this with `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force`, 
but nothing is changed :

```
 Moderate        Command Injection                                             

  Package         dot                                                           

  Patched in      No patch available                                            

  Dependency of   @compodoc/compodoc [dev]                                      

  Path            @compodoc/compodoc > @compodoc/ngd-transformer > dot          

  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/798                        

found 1 moderate severity vulnerability in 37838 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Thanks for your help .

Comment: Most of the time you won't be able to. There are only a few solutions. Downgrade/Upgrade package, wait for the fix from the library creator or create a pull request on library repository by yourself with the fix. Still, there are some hacks but does not worth the time.

Comment: @compodoc/compodoc > @compodoc/ngd-transformer > dot 
this path is for what please and how can i Downgrade/Upgrade package